# PHP preg_replace seems to affect only one match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to find anything that conforms to

```
<element ... bentleysoft-widget="mywidget" ...></element>
```

and replace it with something else.

My actual string is:

```
$text = '<div id="joboftheday" bentleysoft-widget="joboftheday"></div><div id="adults" bentleysoft-widget="test"></div>';
```

My preg_replace expression is this:

```
$output = preg_replace('|<.*bentleysoft-widget="([a-z]+)"></.*>|', 'zzz $1', $text, -1);
```

However, what I get back is this:

```
zzz test
```

So it seems that, for some reason, it only picks up one occurrence. Any ideas will be much appreciated, I've spent over three hours reading and scratching my head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` is *greedy*. Take a look at this pattern `/foo.*bar/` and the following text

```
foo hello bar world bar
```

The `.*` would match `hello bar world` because of the last `bar`.

To change this behaviour, you can simply add a `?`, so the pattern would look like this

```
|<.*?bentleysoft-widget="([a-z]+)"></.*?>|
```

and it should work

---

Also since you want to capture the right closing tag, you should use a [backreference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) here

```
|<(\S+?).*?bentleysoft-widget="([a-z]+)"></\\1>|
```

`(\S+?)` will get you the correct tag name (because `\S` matches everything but whitespaces), which can be backreferenced via `\\1` (1 because it is the first group).

Comment: That's perfect. I am sorry I can't vote you up, I have no cred but really thank you!

Comment: @user3470348 You're welcome and no problem. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted though ;)

Comment: I must be an idiot but I can't see how you mark an answer as accepted. I will keep deciphering the page options ;p)

Comment: Blimey, that was hard. I had to google how to mark a stackoverflow question as answered. The tick icon on the left is anything but obvious!